# How to fork() n child processes doing diferrent functions?

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork

This is my code:

```
for (c = 0; c < PROCESSES; c++) {
    pid[c] = fork();
    switch (pid[c]) {
        case -1:
            perror("Faild fork!\n");
            break;
        case 0:
            printf("C = %d\n", c);
            if (c == 0) {
                printf("MY ID0 %d\n", getpid());
                customers();
                break;
            }
            if (c == 1) {
                printf("MY ID1 %d\n", getpid());
                cashier();
                break;
            }
            if (c == 2) {
                printf("MY ID2 %d\n", getpid());
                sales();
                break;
            }
            if (c == 3) {
                printf("MY ID3 %d\n", getpid());
                warehouse();
                break;
            }
            break;

        default:
            if (c == (PROCESSES - 1)) {

                for (j = 0; j < PROCESSES; j++) {
                    w = wait(&state);
                    if (w == -1) {
                        perror("Erro na espera!\n");
                    }
                    printf("Terminar processo %d\n", w);
                }
                sleep(2);
                printf("Fim da simulação.\n\n");
                free_shm_sem();
            }

    }
}
```

What I was expecting to happen:

```
C = 0
MY ID0 3904
C = 1
MY ID1 3905
C = 2
MY ID2 3906
C = 3
MY ID3 3907
```

what happened:

```
C = 0
MY ID0 3904
C = 1
MY ID1 3905
C = 2
MY ID2 3906
C = 3
MY ID3 3907
C = 3
MY ID3 3911
```

If I change to:

```
            if (c == 0) {
                printf("MY ID0 %d\n", getpid());
                customers();
                break;
            }
            if (c == 1) {
                printf("MY ID1 %d\n", getpid());
                sales();
                break;
            }
            if (c == 2) {
                printf("MY ID2 %d\n", getpid());
                cashier();
                break;
            }
            if (c == 3) {
                printf("MY ID3 %d\n", getpid());
                warehouse();
                break;
            }
```

The output became:

```
C = 0
C = 2
C = 1
MY ID0 3960
MY ID2 3962
C = 3
MY ID1 3961
MY ID3 3963
C = 2
MY ID2 3967
C = 3
MY ID3 3968
```

Why c changes its value and some times passes through the same place twice?

This isnt the right way of fork() n childs doing diferent processes?

P.S. Sorry my English is bad. I hope you can understand what I said.

Answer (score 6):

Are you considering the fact that all your forked processes continue to iterate the for loop and fork more processes?

Consider the first iteration:

```
for (c = 0; c < PROCESSES; c++) { // c is 0
```

we do a fork:

```
 pid[c] = fork();
```

Now, in the child process, `pid[0]` is 0. So,

```
switch (pid[c]) {
```

Goes into:

```
case 0:
       if (c == 0) {
            printf("MY ID0 %d\n", getpid());
            customers();
            break;
        }
```

And does some printing. Then it goes out of switch. And `c` is 0. So it increments `c` to 1, and does:

```
 pid[c] = fork();
```

Forking a grand children.

To prevent this you can `exit` instead of `break`:

```
        if (c == 0) {
            printf("MY ID0 %d\n", getpid());
            customers();
            exit(0);
        }
```

Comment: Your saying that some chield processes are forking their own chields?

Comment: Thats confusing me cause there is the if condition.

Comment: You said that each chield are forking some other processes right? But it apeens cause its inside the for? How could I fork then 4 processes and wait for them?

Comment: Nice awswer, thanks. So if I change break to exit, I will have 1 father that creates n chield, with no subchields?

Comment: Well but with exit, the father wont wait for chields or no?

Comment: it will wait for them and it will continue when they `exit`

Comment: Thank you, you solved my problem. I changed it to exit and now all of my processes are in harmony :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `fork` starts parellel processes, there is no guarantee that it will run sequentially

Comment: I dont want it to run sequentially. But i dont want repeated processes if you understand...

Answer (score 1):

For the processes that should do special handling (i.e. the four first) do a separate step calling `fork` for each of them in the parent process. Then do a loop creating all the generic processes that you might need.